# Is it possible to have pagination with an offset loop?

Tags: pagination, loop, query

I am developing a blog page that requires 3 different post styles (Ie; one full page width with featured image and content, one full page width without featured image and the rest are half page width) so I have been using an offset query.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to force page 2,3, etc. to only use the half page width styles. On top of that I can't get pagination to work anyway

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Offset](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Offset_Parameter) explicitly doesn't work with pagination. You can have either, but not both in same query.

Comment: I feared as much. Is there any way I can style posts differently without offset then?

Comment: @Dean Elliott ehm, of course :) just keep a count when you loop and change markup conditionally... I don't completely get what you are doing to advise something more specific.

Comment: Check this image out, forgive the crudity of it - http://deanelliott.me/misc/layout.jpg this would be page 1 of the blog, and then on other pages all posts would look the same as post 3,4, etc.

Comment: @Dean Elliott seems easy enough... as above - just keep count when you are looping... and output markup, depending on count.

Comment: for the page2 etc question: combine the markup dependency on the count with the conditional tag `is_paged()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged